# Blend for visual studio 2012 disabled for non windows 8 development in update 2 final

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend-2012

When Visual Studio 2012 is released, Blend for Visual Studio 2012 is only enabled for Windows 8 App development. Theres Blend sketchflow preview for visual studio 2012 for other than windows 8 development. Later, Update 2 ctp is released and Blend for visual studio 2012 is enabled for non windows 8 development. Few day ago, Update 2 final is released and Blend for visual studio 2012 is disabled for non windows 8 development.

My question is, how can i enabled Blend for Visual Studio 2012 for non windows 8 development? preview version have unbearable bugs(tfs on slow connection). i hate microsoft for forcing us to upgrade to its crappy os just so i can use the latest dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem and found a solution: Just do a repair of the VS 2012 Update 2 install.
Go to Control Panel, Programs, View installed updates, select Visual Studio Update 2, select Change, Select Repair.

Yes, it sounds weird to do an update and immediately a repair of that update but in my case it worked. I found this solution somewhere on blendinsider.com. It is some bug in the upgrade process.

Comment: you were right. did that and can confirm the solution works. i also found the solution from blendinsider. they dont even issue official press to announce the bug.